# what is difference of "develop" and "origin/develop" in command git

Tags: git, command, push

I'm newbie and starting use git for project.
I not notice the difference of "Branch" and "origin/Branch"
Please guide me.
[image: Picture of the challenge that I've faced]

Comment: develop is a branch local in your pc, origin/develop is a branch in the repo

Comment: `$ git branch
  develop
  developByMohammadEmad
  developByMohsen
* developByMorteza
  master
 `

Comment: `$ git branch -r
  origin/develop
  origin/developByMohammadEmad
  origin/developByMohsen
  origin/developByMorteza
  origin/master `

Comment: `$ git branch -a
  develop
  developByMohammadEmad
  developByMohsen
* developByMorteza
  master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/developByMohammadEmad
  remotes/origin/developByMohsen
  remotes/origin/developByMorteza
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: The most important thing you can do when you're new to git is learn about git, you should go read the [git pro](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book, [check](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) [out](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) [various](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials) [tutorials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Branch` is your local branch and `origin/Branch` is your remote branch.

To make sure which branches are local or remote just use the following git commands.

```
$ git branch     # see local branches
$ git branch -r  # see remote branches
$ git branch -a  # see local and remote branches
```

Comment: When Should use `$git push origin/develop`
And when `$git push develop`?

Comment: You never `push` to your local branch, it's updated by a `commit` or by a `pull` (simplified).

Comment: I understand what you say
But
So why is there this command?

Comment: These commands are helpful to make sure which branches are local or remote.